# How to get pictures off an old LG Flip Phone?

Tags: mobile-phone

I am trying to save the photos from an LG gplg440gb flip phone to my computer so they can be backed up.  The phone works fine as far as I can tell.  It can make calls, take photos and play the built-in games fine.  I have tried using the micro usb connection, which didn't work.  The phone can charge through the USB but the computer never detects it.  I have tried on other computers and with other cables, to no avail.  I have tried both LG Bridge and LG PC Suite, neither of which worked.

If this isn't possible for an end-user to do, are there any companies that can do it?  These photos have a lot of sentimental value and I'd hate to lose them when the phone inevitably dies.

Comment: Does the phone take SD cards? You might be able to transfer the images to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://tracfoneusermanual.net/lg-440g-manual/) for that phone, you may have a couple of viable options. The manual isn't very clear about the one more promising choice, but you can view the album and select images, then select "send via" to transfer the photos selected. It's possible that you can do only one at a time, but that's not clear from the manual.

The phone is also bluetooth capable and references  in the manual lead me to believe that you might be able to make a bluetooth connection to another device and send the images through that connection.

The exploded view of the phone shows the location of the SIM card, and implies that the photos are stored there (not a certainty). If so, there are inexpensive SIM card readers similar to USB flash drives that would provide physical connectivity to another device.

Additionally, eBay shows rather low prices for the phone, almost certainly lower than a recovery service would charge. You'd be able to purchase another of the same model, transfer your card and use the software packages you've noted.

It looks promising for your objective.

Comment: Thank you!!  I wasn't able to do the transfer directly to my PC with bluetooth, but I was able to transfer to a 2nd phone via bluetooth.  It was a real chore, because I could only transfer 10 at a time.  But once they were on a 2nd, more modern phone, connecting that to my PC was simple via USB.  Again, thank you.